# Arduino board cannot measure resistance correctly

Tags: arduino, resistors

This is my first time using Arduino Uno. I’m trying to measure the resistance of a self-made resistor. It's made of 2 copper plate with a conductive foam in between. The resistance will change when pressue is applied to the copper plate. I have the circuit diagram and C code for this measurement. I test them with regular resistor and it works. However, when I replace the regular resistor with the plates the data became weird. For example, when I connect one plate to the multimeter it shows 100k ohms, and if I add a regular 100k ohms in series, each of them should take half of the input voltage. However when I build such circuit the regular 100k ohm resistor will have 2/3 of the input voltage. I tried two different Arduino board and they give same result. Could you guys provide some suggestions here on how to fix this issue?
[image: diagram]

```
int analogPin = 0;
int raw = 0;
int Vin = 5;
float Vout = 0;
float R1 = 100000; //This is the known resistor resistance
float R2 = 0;
float buffer = 0;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
    /*
    This value is a 10-bit analog representation of 0-5V. 
    This means that it will be some value between 0 and 1023. 
    To get the actual voltage value (or at least as close as we can get with a 10-bit resolution), 
    we multiply times Vin, then divide by 1024. So, if the voltage read at pin 0 is 2.4V, 
    it will be read into raw as 492.
    */
    raw = analogRead(analogPin);  
    if(raw){
        buffer = raw * Vin;
        Vout = (buffer)/1024.0;
        buffer = (Vin/Vout) - 1;
        R2= R1 * buffer;
        Serial.print("Vout: ");
        Serial.println(Vout);
        Serial.print("R2: ");
        Serial.println(R2);
        delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: So is the Arduino measuring wrong or right? Do Arduino and multimeter readings agree or not?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the Arduino. Measure the voltage across each resistor with your multimeter and run the calculation manually to see if it matches that reported on the serial port. Update your question with those details.

Comment: What is the resistance of your resistor using a DMM?  Unpressed and pressed.  Now put in series with 100KΩ.  Measure the resistance of your resistor and total resistance, unpressed and pressed.  Now put the two in your arduino, and measure voltages across both resistors, unpressed and pressed.  I believe you will find where it breaks at that point.

Comment: The code looks OK, you may add some unwanted resistors if you touch the plates with fingers. A capacitor >= 100 nF in parallel to the known resistor can suppress RF signals collected by the metal plate and wiring.

Comment: @Justme, no they don't agree, on the DMM it says 100k on my self-made resistor. In arduino it says 50k

Comment: @Transistor yes I measure the voltage over those two resistors and it matches the report on the serial port

Comment: My experience is that trying to make a force sensitive resistor the way you have yields very unsatisfying results, and that spending time trying to debug them is nonproductive.  You can save yourself a ton of aggravation by buying a commercial force sensitive resistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Me: I don't think the problem is with the Arduino. Measure the voltage across each resistor with your multimeter and run the calculation manually to see if it matches that reported on the serial port. Update your question with those details.

> You: Yes, I measure the voltage over those two resistors and it matches the report on the serial port.

Good. So your Arduino and code is working. Your self-made resistor isn't working as you think. You might find that its resistance is voltage dependent.

If you have access to a variable-voltage power supply then you can try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZRkyS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Test circuit.*

Monitor the current at each voltage setpoint and plot a graph. If it's a straight line running from (0, 0) then it's a resistor. If not then you've got a voltage-dependent resistor.

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem is with my self-made resistor. When I replace it with a potentiometer it works properly.